# R package heatmap.plus ColSideColors parameters gives an error on dimensions

Tags: r, heatmap

I need to plot a heatmap of a matrix with annotations, so using the heatmap.plus R package I need to use the ColSideColors parameter. The issue here is that it asks for the same dimensions even when those are equal...

```
> m <- matrix(rnorm(100,1, 20), 10, 10)
> c <- t(as.matrix(rep('gold', 10), ncol=10, nrow=10))
> heatmap.plus(m, ColSideColors=c)
Error in heatmap.plus(m, ColSideColors = c) : 
  'ColSideColors' dim()[2] must be of length ncol(x)
> dim(c)[2]
[1] 10
> ncol(m)
[1] 10
```

---

**UPDATE**
What in the case of the following code?

```
> m <- matrix(rnorm(100,1, 20), 10, 10)
> c <- t(as.matrix(cbind(rep('gold', 10), rep('blue', 10)), ncol=2, nrow=10))
> heatmap.plus(m, ColSideColors=c)
Error in heatmap.plus(m, ColSideColors = c) : 
  'ColSideColors' dim()[2] must be of length ncol(x)
> dim(c)[2]
[1] 10
> ncol(m)
[1] 10
```

in other words, what should I do when I want to build the matrix from vectors...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `c` is causing the issue. Your c is a matrix by 1 (row) x 10 (columns). But, `heatmap.plus` is expecting 10 rows. By following your example, this is what I have done.

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(100, 1, 20), 10, 10)
c <- matrix("gold", ncol = 10, nrow = 10)

heatmap.plus(m, ColSideColors=c)
```

[image]

I followed the example in the CRAN manual and did the following as well. If necessary, have a look.

```
m = matrix(rnorm(100,1, 20), 10, 10)
rlab = matrix(c("gold", "green", "blue", "red"), nrow = 10, ncol = 4)
clab = matrix(c("green", "blue"), nrow = 10, ncol =2)
colnames(rlab) = LETTERS[1:dim(rlab)[2]]
colnames(clab) = 1:dim(clab)[2]

heatmap.plus(m,ColSideColors=clab,RowSideColors=rlab)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! But in my case this was only an example, the real issue is when the matrix is obtained by cbinding vectors... I edited the question to be clearer! :D

Comment: @Qerubin You mean something like this? `matrix(c("green","gold"),ncol = 2, nrow = 10)`?

Comment: No, I mean when the matrix is obtained by something like `matrix(c(rep('gold',10),rep('green',10)), ncol=2, nrow=10)`... in that case it does not work... :/

Comment: @Qerubin I used your code above (i.e.,`matrix(c(rep('gold',10),rep('green',10)), ncol=2, nrow=10)`), and it worked for me. But, `t(as.matrix(cbind(rep('gold', 10), rep('blue', 10)), ncol=2, nrow=10))` is not correct for `heatmap.plus` because the matrix is 2 (rows) x 10 (columns).

Comment: Oh now I got it, in the vector that I converted in matrix I had some NULL values that got lost with the conversion, that was the error! Thank you so much for your support :D

Comment: @Qerubin Glad to hear that you found a way.